# How to bring windows back up, after opening a new window on the desktop in Win10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, desktop, hotkeys

***Question::***

How to bring windows back up, after opening a new window on the desktop in Win10?

***Situation::***

Lets say you have 3 windows of applications `A, B, C` currently opened on your screen, and welly organized.
And you want to open another window of an other app `D` which locates on the desktop.

So you press `Win + D`, to bring up the desktop. And then double click to open the `D`.
Now your screen has the window of `D` on.

>>***Attempt::***

**Now** you want to **bring all the windows of `A, B, C` back up, with `D` on top**, you will have to click on  them one by one (or `alt + tab`).

Is there a faster way to do this?

(Imagine `A, B, C` are files you need to constantly look at. And `D` is the text editor you need to be typing on, every time you look through a paragraph of one of the files `A, B, C`.)

---

***Tried::***

Normally, what I would do is::

Say, Now I have 3 windows of applications `A, B, C` currently opened.

I press `Win + D` to bring up desktop, and then double click on the app `D` I want to open,

then quickly press `Win + D` again (within 0.5s), to bring back up `A, B, C` before the window of `D` pop up.

And then, wait for `D` pop up, so that I can work on it with all the `A, B, C` behind the layer of `D`.

But this is silly and does not work all the time.

Comment: If you have multiple App Windows and need to get back to one particular App, you can move it on the Task Bar to the right hand side and you will very quickly find it.

Comment: Well, once the app `D` is opened. This is not a problem, just `alt + tab`. 
It is a problem when you want to work on more than one `D` (Especially in the case when you are trying to organizing and seeking your files, by clicking shortcut of your folders on your desktop). But I guess it just not a common issue for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Win+M` to minimise all windows. `Shift+Win+M` to unminimise those windows that were minimised.

`Win+D` toggles the desktop to peek at something.

Re your comments. `Win+M` came first. WinMe, Win2000, or WinXp (one of them) introduced a shell shortcut in the Quick Launch area that toggled the desktop and was given `Win+D` as its shortcut key.

That shell shortcut no longer exists. The functionality was moved to the strip at the right hand side of the taskbar.

Comment: It works. 
I knew this `Shift + Win + M` hotkey before, but I don't know why I thought it wouldn't work before. Maybe because it doesn't bring up the newest window on top, though it just one click. Or was due to incompatibility with `Win + D`. 
Anyways, I will use this one now.